# javascript - global variable not in scope after being defined in callback?

Tags: javascript, variables, loops, callback, scope

whenever i try to run something like the following, firebug tells me that "markers is undefined" at the line "for (var i=0 ..."

but i declared markers as a global variable at the top right...?

```
var markers;
function load() {

  $.get("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
    markers = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
  });
  
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name")
    //do more stuff
    }
}
```

but when i do this, it works.

> ```
> var markers;
> function load() {
>
>   $.get("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
>       markers = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
>       makeMarkersWithXMLinfo(); 
>   });
>
>   function makeMarkersWithXMLinfo() {
>       for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
>              var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name")
>              //do more stuff
>       }
>   }
> }
> ```

i'm not even passing "markers" as an argument to my makeMarkersWithXMLinfo() function. but yet it works. what's going on? thnx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you're having is that `get` starts an *asynchronous* operation. So your code immediately following the call to `get` happens *before* the success callback on the `get` is run. E.g. (see the comments):

```
var markers;
function load() {

  // ===> This happens FIRST
  $.get("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
    // ===> This happens THIRD, some time after `load` returns
    markers = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
  });

  // ===> This happens SECOND
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name")
    //do more stuff
    }
}
```

Your second example is the correct way to code it (although I'd recommend avoiding a global entirely), because you're using `markers` only after the GET has completed.

Answer (score 1):

`$.get` is asynchronous, that means that if you call something immediatly after `$.get`, it's callback function wouldn't be invoked yet, and your global would still be undefined.