# Javascript global variable not being set from ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Return Value from inside of $.ajax() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187201/return-value-from-inside-of-ajax-function)

I'm working on a CakePHP app that makes use of widespread AJAX calls to controllers. I'm stuck with one particular AJAX call in which I'm trying to assign the response from the controller to a JS global variable. Here is the code:

```js
window.errors = "";

function setErrors(err) {
    window.errors = err;
}

function ajaxCall(u, t, d, dt) {
    var type = typeof t !== 'undefined' ? t : "post";
    var dataType = typeof dt !== 'undefined' ? dt : "json";
    var success = false;
    var err = "";
    $.ajax({url: url, data: "data=" + d, type: type, dataType: dataType,
        success: function(d){
                if(d.hasOwnProperty('success') === false) { //json response
                    for(var i in d) { //fetch validation errors from object
                        for(var j in i) {
                            if(typeof d[i][j] === "undefined") {
                                continue;
                            }
                            err += d[i][j] + "<br/>";
                        }
                    }
                    console.log(err); //<=== displays correct value
                    setErrors(err); //<=== but somehow this seems to be failing??
                }
                else {
                   if(d.success === "1") {
                       success = true;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return success; //<=== I suspect this might be the culprit
}
```

And this is how ajaxCall() is used:

```js
function register() {
    var data = {};
    var $inputs = $("#regForm :input");
    $inputs.each(function(){
        data[this.name] = $(this).val();
    });
    data = {"User" : data }; //CakePHP compatible object
    data = JSON.stringify(data);

    //Here's the AJAX call
    if(ajaxCall('https://localhost/users/add', 'post', data, 'json')) {
        alert("Registered!");
    }
    else {
        alert(window.errors); // <=== empty string
        console.log("window.errors is: " + window.errors); // <=== empty string
    }
}
```

But on the Chrome JS console, `window.errors` returns the correct value (non-empty, validation error string).

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960803/javascript-global-variable-not-in-scope-after-being-defined-in-callback) that possibly might be addressing my issue (the `return success` immediately following the `$.ajax()` is being executed before the `success:` callback). How can I fix this without drastically changing the code (also, I don't want to make this a synchronous call)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right that the `return` statement runs before the success callback. You can't return the result from the function, as the function has to return before the success event can be handled.

Add a callback to the `ajaxCall` function, and call that instead of setting the success variable:

```
function ajaxCall(u, t, d, dt, callback) {
  var type = typeof t !== 'undefined' ? t : "post";
  var dataType = typeof dt !== 'undefined' ? dt : "json";
  $.ajax({url: url, data: "data=" + d, type: type, dataType: dataType,
    success: function(d){
      if(d.hasOwnProperty('success') === false) { //json response
        for(var i in d) { //fetch validation errors from object
          for(var j in i) {
            if(typeof d[i][j] === "undefined") {
              continue;
            }
            err += d[i][j] + "<br/>";
          }
        }
        callback(false, err);
      } else {
        callback(d.success === "1", "");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Send the code for handling the result into the `ajaxCall` function:

```
ajaxCall('https://localhost/users/add', 'post', data, 'json', function(success, err){
  if (success) {
    alert("Registered!");
  } else {
    alert(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! Yes, your solution worked perfectly. I'm learning quite a few new JS stuff (and many of its quirks) the more I work with it.